# Place WinSCP.exe in project resources for WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using `WinSCPnet.dll` in my project and to run correctly it needs `WinSCP.exe` in the launch directory e.g. `project_path/obj/Debug`. But if I want to use my program, it needs to have this `.exe` file all the time in the same folder otherwise the program will crash.

Is it possible to place `WinSCP.exe` into project resources so I don't have to place it in the same directory every time I move it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `winscp.exe` has to exist as a real file, at the moment you call the `Session.Open`.

So while you can store the `winscp.exe` to your application resources, you have to extract it somewhere (e.g. to a temporary folder), and set the `Session.ExecutablePath` accordingly, before you call the `Session.Open`.

---

Inspired by your question, I have added instructions for [Embedding WinSCP executable as resource](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#resource) to the assembly documentation.